# How to concatenate two variables from azure variable group and assign them to one with single quotes

Tags: azure, powershell

I'm having 2 Variables inside a variable group and their values are as shown below:

```
cr  2200
tr  cd1200
```

I would like to assign these two variables to a third variable cd as shown below:

```
cd  '2200;cd1200;abc.txt'
```

I'm trying to use below script but it is showing too many arguments.
Can someone please help in this.

I'm using below code:

```
cd = \'"$cr";"$tr";abc.txt\'
echo "$cd"
```

I need output as:

```
cd = '2200;cd1200;abc.txt'
```

Comment: ```$cd = "'$cr;$tr;abc.txt'"```

Comment: I'm getting this output: ';;abc.txt' . Variables cr and tr are defined inside variable groups in azure devops. They are not expanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Azure [macro syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#macro-syntax-variables) (`$(<varName>)`):

```bash
$cd = '$(cr);$(tr);abc.txt'
```

Note:

- PowerShell *always* needs the `$` sigil when accessing a variable - even when *assigning* to it (unlike in POSIX-compatible shells such as Bash).
- Azure's macro syntax - which *textually expands* references to Azure variables *up front*, before PowerShell sees the code, is not be confused with PowerShell's [subexpression operator (`$(...)`)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--)